# Still seeing old shard after calling SPLITSHARD

Tags: solr

I called splitshard, and now this is what I see even after posting a commit:

[image]

I thought splitshard was supposed to get rid of the original shard, shard1, in this case. Am I missing something? I was expecting the only two remaining shards to be shard1_0 and shard1_1.

The REST call I used was /admin/collections?collection=default-collection&shard=shard1&action=SPLITSHARD if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from the Solr mailing list:

Once the SPLITSHARD call completes, it just marks the original shard as
Inactive i.e. it no longer accepts requests. So yes, you would have to use
DELETESHARD (
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api7)
to clean it up.

As far as what you see on the admin UI, that information is wrong i.e. the
UI does not respect the state of the shard while displaying them. So,
though the parent shard might be inactive, you still would end up seeing it
as just another active shard. There's an open issue for this one.

One way to confirm the shard state is by looking at the shard state in
clusterstate.json (or state.json, depending upon the version of Solr you're
using).